# iPhone Loading Screen Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to figure out how apps like Convertbot and Appzilla, have loading screens that fades away at both ends.  I attached a picture because it is hard to explain.  Any ideas, suggestion, tutorial.  I'd love to implement this into my app.

[image: Convertbot loading screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. They've got a default graphic (Default.png) that shows the initial screen. Once the application has loaded, the very first view that comes up has the very same graphic, providing a seamless transition between the startup screen and the application. There's a short delay before an animation of some sort within the view opens up the doors and reveals the main navigation.